# How to mock uuid4() in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, patch

A_script.py

```
from uuid import uuid4

def get_unique_identifier(env, customer_id):
    return env + '-' + customer_id + '-' + str(uuid4())[0:8]
```

test_A_script.py

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import src.A_script as a_script

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   @patch('uuid.uuid4')
   def test_get_unique_identifier(self, mock_uuid4):
      mock_uuid4.return_value = 'abcd1234'
      expected = 'test_env-test_cust-abcd1234'
      unique_identifier = a_script.get_unique_identifier('test_env', 'test_cust')
      self.assertEqual(expected, unique_identifier)
```

How can I make uuid4 return 'abcd1234'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to patch uuid that are imported in your srcipt, so change

```
@patch('uuid.uuid4')
```

to

```
@patch('src.A_script.uuid4')
# or @patch('src.A_script.uuid4', return_value="abcd1234")
# or @patch('src.A_script.uuid4', new=lambda:"abcd1234")
```

In last case you do not pass mock as function parameter at all

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the method in the module where it's used. In your case you use it in module `A_script` so you have to call `patch` with `'A_script.uuid4`.